# Why would Evaluate[] in Plot give me warning about precision?

Tags: plotting, evaluation, machine-precision, precision-and-accuracy

I have a code:-

```
Plot[Evaluate@PDF[NormalDistribution[1.6, 0.2], x], {x, -6, 6}]
```

And then I got the warning: `General::munfl: Exp[-721.953] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost`. However, if I removed `Evaluate`, the warning disappears. Why would that? Would that matter?

I need to keep the `Evaluate`, since I am drawing various distributions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you use [`Evaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate), the [`PDF`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PDF) evaluates to an exponential:

```
pdf = PDF[NormalDistribution[1.6, .2], x]
```

> 1.99471 E^(-12.5 (-1.6 + x)^2)

When you evaluate this object with a large enough number x (on the order of 10), the resulting object is too small to represent as a machine number:

```
pdf /. x -> 10
```

> General::munfl: Exp[-882.] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.
>
> 0.

Let's check. The smallest machine number is:

```
$MinMachineNumber
```

> 2.22507*10^-308

If we convert the `pdf` expression to one using extended precision numbers:

```
epdf = SetPrecision[pdf, 20];
```

and then evaluate `epdf` at 10:

```
epdf /. x->10
```

> 1.7870924971057366*10^-383

We see that the result is much smaller than the smallest possible machine number. This is why evaluating `pdf` at 10 produces an error message and Mathematica returns 0.

Now, when you remove the [`Evaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate), then [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot) only evaluates the [`PDF`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PDF) object when it is numerical, and this doesn't produce any messages:

```
PDF[NormalDistribution[1.6, .2], 10]
```

> 1.787092497106*10^-383

Of course, the above output is not a machine number:

```
Precision @ PDF[NormalDistribution[1.6, .2], 10]
```

> 13.0095

If you are multiplying extremely small numbers with extremely large numbers, then setting the small numbers to zero can be an issue. In that case, it makes sense to work with extended precision numbers instead.